# Converting Array type in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Please Help in conversion of an array from one form to another I Have This Array

```
Array ( 
    [mpr_last_month] => 376431 
    [mpr_month] => 03 
    [total_boys_all_6m_36m] => 5550225 
    [total_girls_all_6m_36m] => 5215529 
    [total_boys_all_36m_72m] => 4209639 
    [total_girls_all_36m_72m] => 4149613 
    [total_pse_boys_36m_72m] => 4442301 
    [total_pse_all_girls_36m_72m] => 4413446 
    [total_pregnanting] => 2209158 ) 



Array (
    [mpr_last_month] => 448216 
    [mpr_month] => 04 
    [total_boys_all_6m_36m] => 7153209 
    [total_girls_all_6m_36m] => 6798913 
    [total_boys_all_36m_72m] => 5175846 
    [total_girls_all_36m_72m] => 5105460 
    [total_pse_boys_36m_72m] => 5290617 
    [total_pse_all_girls_36m_72m] => 5263340 
    [total_pregnanting] => 2944612 
    ) 

Array ( 
    [mpr_last_month] => 448253 
    [mpr_month] => 05 
    [total_boys_all_6m_36m] => 11742417 
    [total_girls_all_6m_36m] => 6362815 
    [total_boys_all_36m_72m] => 4879252 
    [total_girls_all_36m_72m] => 4756805 
    [total_pse_boys_36m_72m] => 5344042 
    [total_pse_all_girls_36m_72m] => 5095155 
    [total_pregnanting] => 2852864 

    )

Array ( 
    [mpr_last_month] => 470848 
    [mpr_month] => 06 
    [total_boys_all_6m_36m] => 6552523 
    [total_girls_all_6m_36m] => 6217771 
    [total_boys_all_36m_72m] => 4613019 
    [total_girls_all_36m_72m] => 4551685 
    [total_pse_boys_36m_72m] => 5182666 
    [total_pse_all_girls_36m_72m] => 5165730 
    [total_pregnanting] => 2746293 
    ) 

Array ( 
    [mpr_last_month] => 465489 
    [mpr_month] => 07 
    [total_boys_all_6m_36m] => 6638749 
    [total_girls_all_6m_36m] => 6310676 
    [total_boys_all_36m_72m] => 4801665 
    [total_girls_all_36m_72m] => 4657764 
    [total_pse_boys_36m_72m] => 5020964 
    [total_pse_all_girls_36m_72m] => 5051785 
    [total_pregnanting] => 2815773

    )
```

I Want This

```
 name: 'mpr_last_month',
 data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133,  154175,123,123,123,123]
```

.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) function. But be aware that this function works only for PHP >= 5.5.0. Try this:

```
//example data
$array = [
    ['a' => 2, 'b'=>3, 'c'=>6],
    ['a' => 12, 'b'=>13, 'c'=>16],
    ['a' => 22, 'b'=>23, 'c'=>26],
];


$result = [];

//get indexes from first element of array
$indexes = array_keys($array[0]);

foreach($indexes as $index) {
    $result[$index] = array_column($array, $index);
}
```

And result is:

```
Array
(
    [a] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 12
            [2] => 22
        )

    [b] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 13
            [2] => 23
        )

    [c] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6
            [1] => 16
            [2] => 26
        )

)
```

Comment: Wow the array_column() function is pretty neat! Didnt know about it, thank sir.

Comment: @ManuelMannhardt, I'm happy that you've learn something new :)

Answer (score 2):

Simplest approach would be foreach loop.

```
$newData = [];
foreach ($yourArray as $innerArray) {
    foreach ($innerArray as $key => $value) {
        $newData[$key][] = $value;
    }
}
```

It loops over the first array (the big one, containg all others), the runs over each inner array and store the value in the correct place.